# Look up lists stop working when the look up list contains more than a few records (XAF)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, xaf

I have a NonPersistentObject for SalesLines with two persistent look up properties Product and TaxRate

The TaxRate look up works correctly, giving me a list all the tax codes in the database.
The Product look up is empty even though there are many products in the database.

The code is

```
private Product _product;
[ImmediatePostData]
public virtual Product ProductRecord
{
        get
        {
            if (_product == null || _product?.ItemId != ItemId)
            {   
               _product = PersistentObjectSpace.FindObject<Product>(CriteriaOperator.Parse("[ItemId] = ?", ItemId));
            }
            return _product;
        }
        set
        {
            _product = value;
            ItemId = _product.ItemId;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductRecord");
        }
}

private TaxRate _taxRate;  

[ImmediatePostData]
public virtual TaxRate TaxRecord
{
        get
        {
            if (_taxRate == null || _taxRate?.TaxCodeId != TaxCodeId)
            {
                _taxRate =
                    PersistentObjectSpace.FindObject<TaxRate>(CriteriaOperator.Parse("[TaxCodeId] = ?", TaxCodeId));
               
            }
            return _taxRate;
        }
        set
        {
            _taxRate = value;
            TaxCodeId = _taxRate.TaxCodeId;
            TaxPercentage = (decimal)_taxRate.Percentage;
            OnPropertyChanged("TaxRecord");
        }
}
```

The entities are

```
[DefaultProperty("ProductCode")]
[NavigationItem("Config")]
public class Product : BasicBo
{
    public Product()
    {
        ExtMaterial = new ExtMaterialProperty();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    [Column("Item Number")] public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(10)] public string UnitName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ItemId")] 
    public virtual ExtMaterialProperty ExtMaterial { get; set;}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ProductCode;
    }
}
```

and

```
[NavigationItem("Configuration")]
[Table("TaxCode")]
[DefaultProperty("TaxCode")]
[ImageName("BO_List")]
public class TaxRate : BasicBo
{
    [Key] public short TaxCodeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RuleRequiredField(DefaultContexts.Save)]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The field cannot exceed 20 characters. ")]
    public string TaxCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RuleRequiredField(DefaultContexts.Save)]
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TaxCode;
    }
}
```

Both DbSets are in the DbContext

I have tried removing the ExtMaterial navigation property from the Product but it has not helped.
I am using XAF 21.1.4, Framework 4.7.2, EF 6.4.4

I did used to have both look ups working.I am not sure what has changed.

[Update]
I will try creating a new lookup table and keep changing it till it breaks.
So far technique works with the following structure and a few records

[NavigationItem("Configuration")]
[Table("FunCat")]
[DefaultProperty("FunCatCode")]
[ImageName("BO_List")]
public class FunCategory : BasicBo
{
[Key] public int FunCatId { get; set; }

```
    public string FunCatCode { get; set; }

    public virtual TaxRate TaxRate { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FunCatCode;
    }
}
```

I discovered that the bad behaviour starts when there are over a certain number of FunCategories in the database.
This number is defined by the Options LookupSmallCollectionItemCount as explained [here](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112925/ui-construction/controllers-and-actions/actions/how-to-add-a-search-action-to-lookup-property-editors-and-link-pop-up-windows)

If there are less than the options number the look up table works
[image: Good look up table]

Otherwise it does not
[image: bad look up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred because I had deactivated the FullTextFilterAction controller.